# Completely Center image and div

Tags: css, position, z-index, center

As you can see here http://dekkro.no-ip.org/

I have two divs, one on top of the other. I would like them to be 100% dead center. with the top div, staying in the center while the page is resized. They are centered to me, but for a lot of people they arent.

I have tried using margins and using percentages, but still isnt perfect. Is there a fix for this?

I am currently using

```
position:absolute; left:32%; top:24%;margin: auto;z-index:-1;
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you tell exactly which divs you're talking about?

Answer (score 2):

If the width and height of your div is fixed you can center it using negative margins.

For example if you have a div of 300x200 you can center it this way :

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Comment: I have followed your instructions and now the image is like this
http://dekkro.no-ip.org/

take a peak

Comment: Ì've checked your CSS, you have positive values in `margin-left` and `margin-right`. They need to be negative.

Comment: Try changing : `margin-left: 345px; margin-top: 212.5px;` to `margin-left: -345px; margin-top: -212.5px;` and removing the `margin: auto` in the style attribute of your image element.

Answer (score 1):

Just messing around quickly on Firebug:

```
<div class="my_img" 
     style="position: absolute; top:50%; width: 100%;">
    <img width="690" 
         height="425" 
         style=" margin: auto;z-index:-1; margin-top: -212px;"  
         src="http://dekkro.no-ip.org/images/testimage.png">
</div>
<div id="container" 
     style="position : absolute; 
                 top : 0; 
               width : 100%; 
         margin-left : auto; 
        margin-right : auto; 
              height : 600px; 
             z-index : 5;">
```

And if you need it to stay centred when scrolling, then make the first line:

```
<div class="my_img" 
     style="position: fixed; top:50%; width: 100%;">
```

Comment: I used this and it worked, but when I check it on my other computer with a different res, they are no longer in place, for example...

see image: http://dekkro.no-ip.org/problem.png

how would I go about fixing this problem?

Comment: i'm guessing i have to put it inside a div?

Comment: Is the problem the vertical alignment of the second div? I've only shown the solution for the first div...

Comment: basically, i want to have the 2nd div centered on that image, no matter what size res anyones on, that div should always be in the middle of the image.

Comment: Vertical centering of divs with unknown heights is a tricky area; what browsers do you need to support?

Comment: chrome, safari and firefox mainly

Comment: Stobor do you have MSN? I would like to talk to you about it in a quicker way, please add me dekky@live.co.uk - you can delete me afterwards if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day I did it like describe here : http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html

Maybe there is a better more modern way now, otherwise you could use that...